# Ethernet not recognized on Intel Nuc with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ethernet, intel-nuc

Got an Intel Nuc NUC6CAYS and first tried installing Ubuntu 14.04, yet the system couldn't get online, recognizing neither the wireless nor wired hardware/driver. Then I installed Ubuntu 16.04 and now I can connect via the wireless, but not over ethernet.

ifconfig does not list any ethernet device. wlp4s0 is the wireless.

```
$ ifconfig -a
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:745 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:75656 (75.6 KB)  TX bytes:75656 (75.6 KB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:e3:7a:9c:53:83  
          inet addr:192.168.1.157  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::776c:ccb5:7dc2:3f54/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:47243 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16047 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:65657395 (65.6 MB)  TX bytes:1735984 (1.7 MB)
```

Ethernet also does not show up with lshw, not even as unclaimed

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 30:e3:7a:9c:53:83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-46-generic firmware=22.361476.0 ip=192.168.1.157 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:373 memory:91100000-91101fff
```

When I plug in an ethernet cable there is no blinking lights on the NUC itself, but there is blinking on my switch, indicating it recognized a plugged-in device.

---

EDIT:
Seems it fixed itself over night. I did a bunch of debugging, my main suspicion is that it fixed itself with one of the `sudo apt-get update` updates, but who knows ...

The ethernet is now listed as `enp3s0` in `ifconfig`.

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp3s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:4d:30:6a:c2:bf  
          inet addr:192.168.1.110  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::954b:d966:8b17:9447/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:336 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:341 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:66732 (66.7 KB)  TX bytes:115422 (115.4 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:78527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:78527 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:101224398 (101.2 MB)  TX bytes:101224398 (101.2 MB)

wlp4s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 30:e3:7a:9c:53:83  
          inet addr:192.168.1.157  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::fc9e:7183:6bd6:dc39/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:109195 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:131436 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:26589471 (26.5 MB)  TX bytes:87907317 (87.9 MB)
```

And lshw now lists this:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for airnuc: 
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 10
       serial: 30:e3:7a:9c:53:83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.8.0-46-generic firmware=22.361476.0 ip=192.168.1.157 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:374 memory:91200000-91201fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 15
       serial: f4:4d:30:6a:c2:bf
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:371 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:91104000-91104fff memory:91100000-91103fff
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is pretty old, but it's still a top result for NUC ethernet not working on Linux Mint. So here's my report, made in the hope that it might help someone else.

The solution for my NUC5i5RY system was to upgrade the BIOS to RY0367.bio. This works great with a clean Linux Mint 18.3 install + updates, using version 3.2.6-k of the e1000e Network Driver. I use the legacy boot.

EDIT: here's a few more details on how I did this. And thanks to J. Starnes for the suggestion that add to this post.

You can get Intel's BIOS updates from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/ There's a couple of different ways you can upgrade your BIOS on the NUC. A page that explains the various methods is here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005636/mini-pcs.html. All methods require a USB device, with the exception of systems running a Windows OS.

I picked the "power button BIOS menu update method." That meant grabbing the correct BIOS and writing it to a FAT32 USB key. For my NUC5i5RY this was the recovery BIOS from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/27230/BIOS-Update-RYBDWi35-86A-. One note: even though the section for recovery BIOS does not talk specifically about using it for power button menu updates, it does work in that scenario.

The power button BIOS menu update method is described here: https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/boardsandkits/BIOS-Recovery-Update-Instructions.pdf. The TL;DR is that you insert your USB key when the NUC is off, and then you hold down the power button for three seconds. You are then get dumped into simple menu system. The menu offers you F4, a BIOS recovery option, and F7, a BIOS update. The F4 option is for recovering from an interrupted BIOS flash. Since I was just doing an upgrade I picked F7. It took a couple of minutes.

And when I booted in Linux Mint I had a working Ethernet port, yay! :)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu.com. Answering old questions is encouraged here. However it would improve your answer if you [included](https://askubuntu.com/posts/984755/edit) specific steps. - From [Review](https://askubuntu.com/review/first-posts/784491)

Comment: Do you mean `RY0357.bio`?

Comment: No, as of 12/12/2017, the latest recovery BIOS for this model NUC is RY0367.bio, so that's what I installed.

Answer (score 1):

For me, I updated the BIOS to the latest version from intel, which didn't improve things with Ubuntu 16.04.   I then installed Ubuntu 17.10, and miraculously networking was healthy.

NUC7i7
KY0053.bio

Comment: +1. When you have a new computer, it is often a good idea to try a new version of Ubuntu. The reason is that it brings a new version of the Linux kernel, and the kernel brings new versions of hardware drivers. See also this link, [How to select the version and flavour of Ubuntu](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13540865#post13540865)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 desktop doesn't have hardware level drivers for some NUC devices like latest NUC8i7BEH. So, you can use  [Dawson Canyon and June Canyon NUC – Ubuntu Desktop 16.04](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc-desktop). It is tested and works great.